# SharpGL and Geometry Shader

Tags: c#, opengl, shader, sharpgl

Have anyone used geometry shaders in SharpGL? I cannot figure out how to accomplish it in my code. As I see method `Create` which is provided with `ShaderProgram` from `SharpGL.Shaders` take only `Vertex Shader` and `Fragment Shader` as parameters.

```
public void Create(
  OpenGL gl,
  string vertexShaderSource,
  string fragmentShaderSource,
  Dictionary<uint, string> attributeLocations
);
```

How can I link my geometry shader with OpenGL via SharpGL? Or I need to use another approach to get `Geometry Shader` worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to my own question. Quite a straightforward OpenGL approach can be applied for this issue. All that's needed is to create a geometry shader, compile it and than attach to program.

```
uint program = gl.CreateProgram();
uint geom = gl.CreateShader(OpenGL.GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
gl.ShaderSource(shader, geometryShaderSourceString);
gl.CompileShader(shader);
gl.AttachShader(program, geom);
```